# accessing session variables in redirected file in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am building a crappy login system as a newbie. I have done this so far:

```
app.post("/verifyLogin",function(request,response){
var usr=request.body.username;
var pass=request.body.password;

userModel.find({$and:[{username:usr},{password:pass}]},function(err,user){

if(user.length==0)
{
    response.redirect("/?msg=failed");
}
else
{
    request.session.user=user;
    response.redirect("/dashboard");

}

 });

    });
```

This works fine but after successful login i want to get the user details in the dashboard. I am clueless. Please shed some light.

**EDIT**

I have the following setup for dashboard in routes:

```
app.get("/dashboard",function(request,response){
response.sendfile('/lms/site/dashboard.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to pass the users' details to a template:

```
app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
  res.render('dashboard', {
    user : req.session.user
  });
});
```

This assumes a few things though:

- you have a working templating setup;
- you have a template called `dashboard` (with an extension matching your templating setup);
- you're going to provide some sort of setup to make sure a user is logged in before they can open `/dashboard`.

**EDIT:** since you don't want to use templating, you could use AJAX to get the user details from the server into the client:

```
// server side
app.get('/userdata', function(req, res) {
  // check if a user is logged in
  ...
  // return the user details as JSON
  res.send(req.session.user);
});

// client side (in 'dashboard.html', this assumes is will load jQuery)
$.getJSON('/userdata', function(user) {
  // process user data, insert it into the DOM somewhere...
});
```

**EDIT 2:** to check if a user is logged in, you could create a middleware which would check for the existence of `req.session.user` and redirect to the login page if it's undefined:

```
var isLoggedIn = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session && req.session.user)
    next(); // user logged in, so pass
  else
    res.redirect('/'); // not logged in, redirect to login page
};
```

You would use the `isLoggedIn` middleware for all routes that require a user to be logged in:

```
app.get('/userdata', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  res.send(req.session.user);
});
```

Comment: in dashboard route, i serve my html directly. I am not using any templating engine and don't want to. Please see my edit.

Comment: If you don't want to use templating, you'd have to resort to some sort of AJAX setup to pass the user details from the server to the client.

Comment: ajax for passing data from server to client? how do i do it in my case?

Comment: how should i check if a user is logged in the server side mentioned in your code. I get a undefined if i console.log a request.session.user

Comment: which framework you are using express? have you enabled session?

Comment: it throws 302 Moved Temporarily in the network console...when fetched the /userdata url

Comment: Well, apparently you're either not logged in (and it redirects you to the login page, which – silly me – is a bit pointless for AJAX requests) or your user details aren't stored in `req.session` properly (but since you wrote 'it works fine' I'm assuming that part works).